# MyBatis: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getBuildingTypes

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have searched a lot about this issue, seems they are all about the configuration of MyBatis. But I have a different situation here. For my case, others are working well except this one:

```
<select id="getBuildingTypes" resultType="com.xxx.vo.Dict">
    SELECT id, value, label, type, description, sort, parent_id parentId
    FROM sys_dict
    WHERE type = 'building_type' AND del_flag = '0'
    AND value in
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="array" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{item}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

The most weird part is that it works in my local environment (Mac), though I don't think this is related. It's been deployed on a Windows machine and started the same way I did at my local environment.

I even tried to copy this snippet from my local to the server in case the code is not up to date, but I got no luck.

Can someone shed some light on it? Thanks in advance!